# Comprobar si existe un fichero o imagen con javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hola que tal buenas noches, mostrando unas fotos que se suben al registrar mediante un form. Todo bien. Tengo 5 fotos que subo. Pero de esas 5, cuatro son obligatorias.
Despues en un panel estoy mostrandolas, lo que quiero hacer es que si esa foto 5 que no es obligatoria, cuando la llamo, y no existe, poner una foto predeterminada, o si bien, que no se muestre el error de la imagen chiquitica de la etiqueta img

estoy intentandolo hacer coon

```
try {
if(fs.accessSync('../../estilos/imagenes/imgRegister/'+DatosDelSolicitante[0].nroDoc+'mono.jpg')) {
 console.log("existe")
}
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("nolsa")
  }
```

Pero no logro comprobar su existencia, y las rutas estan buenas.

part de mi codigo

```
   function MostrarCuerpoNotificacion() {
    $('.body-despliegue').click(function () {//
      let elementoRequerido = $(this)[0];
      let id = $(elementoRequerido).attr("tomoDato");

$.post('../../model/noti-work/request-data-notifications.php', { id }, function (response) {
  var DatosDelSolicitante = JSON.parse(response);
  let template = "<h4>Datos del solicitante </h4>";
  console.log(DatosDelSolicitante[0].tipoDeSolicitud);
  
   if(DatosDelSolicitante[0].tipoDeSolicitud === 'Empleado' || DatosDelSolicitante[0].tipoDeSolicitud 
   === 'Recolector' || DatosDelSolicitante[0].tipoDeSolicitud === 'Call Center'){
    console.log("es un empleado o recolector")
     console.log('../../estilos/imagenes/imgRegister/'+DatosDelSolicitante[0].nroDoc+'mono.jpg')



    try {
    if(fs.accessSync('../../estilos/imagenes/imgRegister/'+DatosDelSolicitante[0].nroDoc+'mono.jpg')) 
     {
     console.log("existe")
    }
    } catch (e) {
     console.log("nolsa")
    }



    }
```

como podria comprobar su existencia y hacer que aparezca una imagen por defecto o directamente q no muestre nada.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const fs = require('fs-extra')

//Usamos el metodo existSync() de fs para comprobar si existe el archivo
if(fs.existsSync('../../estilos/imagenes/imgRegister/'+DatosDelSolicitante[0].nroDoc+'mono.jpg')){
//comprobamos que existe
    console.log('Existe')
}else {
//comprobamos que no existe
    console.log('No Existe')
}
```

Es asi de simple como usar el método existSync() de fs. ¡Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Hola himeno-Chan, lo estoy usando adentro de jquery y me dice indefinido. Puede ser pq lo este usando con jquery, o la posicion del llamado del fichero en el html?